# Empty app - can be updated later?

Tags: android

Can one make an empty app in Android (or something very basic), put it on google play, and later on update it?

Comment: You can do that but what is the reason of putting a basic app or empty app. You should not do that

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can update the app.You need to have `keystore` and same `package name` with increment.
Refer this https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could put something very basic (I think an empty app would be refused). But why would you want to do this ? It wouldn't help you "reserve" the name!

Comment: I went to the extreme. The question is if one can change the app later, no matter what the changes are, for example, if one has a basic idea for an app and latter on decides that a better design is more appropriate.

Comment: @Abe yes of course. Right now I am working on a project replacing a hybrid app with the native one. So this is quite a radical change.